# Correct way to create 2 interdependent dropdown boxes with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm starting out with Java and JavaFX and for my first project I need 2 dropdown boxes, A and B. When I choose an item from A, the contents in B change automatically. I've managed to do it using setOnAction, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. Listeners maybe? I have looked a bit into that, but I'm not totally sure how to use them.

This is my code so far:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    String[] mainlist = {"Selector A", "Selector B"};
    String[] options1 = {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"};
    String[] options2 = {"Option 4", "Option 5", "Option 6"};

    primaryStage.setTitle("UI Test");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 450, Color.WHITE);

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

    mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);
    mainPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    mainPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());


    //Create Tab 1
    Tab tab1 = new Tab();
    tab1.setText("TestTab");
    tab1.setClosable(false);

    //Create grid1 and add it to Tab 1
    GridPane grid1 = new GridPane();
    grid1.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    grid1.setHgap(5);
    grid1.setVgap(5);
    grid1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    grid1.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(100));
    grid1.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(300));

    tab1.setContent(grid1);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

    //Add combobox1 to grid1
    grid1.add(new Label("Action:"), 0, 1); //Places label
    ObservableList<String> aComboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < mainlist.length; i++){
        aComboList.add(mainlist[i]);
    }

    ComboBox<String> aBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>(aComboList);
    grid1.add(aBoxProjects, 1, 1);


    //Add combobox2 to grid1
    grid1.add(new Label("Elements:"), 0, 2); //Places label
    ObservableList<String> bComboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ComboBox<String> bBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>(bComboList);
    grid1.add(bBoxProjects, 1, 2);

    root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


    aBoxProjects.setOnAction (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent b) {

            bComboList.clear();

            if (aBoxProjects.getValue().toString() == mainlist[0]){
                for (int i = 0; i < options1.length; i++){
                    bComboList.add(options1[i]);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < options2.length; i++){
                    bComboList.add(options2[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

This is just an initial approach. In time the arrays will be replaced by strings read from a file, etc. Right now I'm more concerned with using JavaFX properly. Are there ways to write the same code in a more elegant manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the amount of code you have and still use the same basic strategy:

```
ObservableList<String> aComboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mainlist);

ComboBox<String> aBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>(aComboList);
grid1.add(aBoxProjects, 1, 1);


//Add combobox2 to grid1
grid1.add(new Label("Elements:"), 0, 2); //Places label

ObservableList<String> bComboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ComboBox<String> bBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>(bComboList);
grid1.add(bBoxProjects, 1, 2);

root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();


aBoxProjects.setOnAction (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent b) {

        if (aBoxProjects.getValue().toString() == mainlist[0]){
            bcomboList.setAll(options1);
        } else {
            bcomboList.setAll(options2);
        }

    }
});
```

and you can use a lambda expression for the event handler instead of the anonymous inner class:

```
aBoxProjects.setOnAction (b -> {
    if (aBoxProjects.getValue() == mainlist[0]){
        bcomboList.setAll(options1);
    } else {
        bcomboList.setAll(options2);
    }
});
```

or even

```
aBoxProjects.setOnAction(b -> 
    bcomboList.setAll(aBoxProjects.getValue() == mainlist[0] ? options1 : options2));
```

You could also use a binding instead of using the event handler:

```
ObservableList<String> aComboList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(mainlist);

ComboBox<String> aBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>(aComboList);
grid1.add(aBoxProjects, 1, 1);


//Add combobox2 to grid1
grid1.add(new Label("Elements:"), 0, 2); //Places label
ObservableList<String> bComboList1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(options1);
ObservableList<String> bComboList2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(options2);
ComboBox<String> bBoxProjects = new ComboBox<String>();
grid1.add(bBoxProjects, 1, 2);

bBoxProjects.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    if (aBoxProject.getValue() ==  mainlist[0]) {
        return bComboList1 ;
    } else if (aBoxProject.getValue() == mainlist[1]) {
        return bComboList2 ;
    } else { // no selection
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }
}, aBoxProject.valueProperty()));       

root.getChildren().add(mainPane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Note that lambdas are only available if you use Java 8

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the comprehensive reply. You've given me quite a bit of material to read, including lambda expressions and bindings :)